# How to get name by ID from other table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a table name "drug". It has column name "ingredians". 
"ingredians" field has text (varchar)

I can select the "ingredians" using dropdown box.

```
<td width="100px"><center>
   <select name="drugitem" style="width:100px; height:30px;" >

    <? $sc="SELECT * FROM drug";
       $scq=mysql_query($sc);
       while($scf=mysql_fetch_array($scq))
        {
    ?><option value='<? echo $scf[id];?>'><? echo $scf[ingredians];?></option>


    <? } ;?>
    </select></center>
</td>
```

And then I want to pass this "ingredians" both ID and VALUE to another table called "temp".
'temp' table has two colomns to catch these data called "drugitemid" and "drugitemname"

How can I pass both values.

Comment: You want to checkout Ajax, for example using jQuery

Comment: I tried many ways .. But only i can pass its ID into the "temp" -> "drugitemid" field . But I failed to pass "ingredians" VALUE to the "temp" -> "drugitemname" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is bit vague. As per my understanding what you need is to concat name with id in value for `ingredients` & than on other page you can use them after exploding with `-`,

```
<option value='<? echo $scf[ingredians].'-'.$scf[id];?>'><? echo $scf[ingredians];?></option>
```

On next page:

```
list($drugname, $drugid) = explode('-', $_POST['drugitem']);
```

**Note:** It's irrelevant to save both foreign id & name in any table.

Comment: It was WORKED !! 
But I want to INSERT these ID and VALUE into TWO colomns. :( 
Like this

$sql = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('', '$_POST[drugitemid]', '$_POST[drugitemname]')";

How can I insert both ID and VALUE into two fields ???

Comment: As I mention, you have to perform an [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) on your posted value, to get them in different variables.

Comment: Can you send me the POST code also ... I am really confused with it :(

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: I want to INSERT these two values into TWO fields... now its INSERT only one field called "drugitem" .. But I want to INSERT these ID into "drugitemid" and VALUE into "drugitemname" using that dropdown box.

Please help me... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery. On this dropdown change event get value from.

```
var val_id = $("#yordropdown_id").val();
var name = $("#yordropdown_id option[value="+val_id+"]").text();
```

Then send ajax request with those id and names and save it to your temp table.

I think it makes sense!